# Remote kernel shuts down after several seconds

Tags: parallelization, kernel, remote-access, kernel-startup

I have Mathematica 9 installed on two Windows Server 2008 R2 machines. Now i want to try using one of them as a frontend with local kernels and the other one for remote kernels.

OpenSSH 6.5 for Windows is installed on both machines and key authentication is configured without a passphrase. SSH connection works normally.

Here is the frontend configuration.
In Preferences -> Parallel -> Remote Kernels i Add Host and use the custom launch command:

```
ssh -l username `1` "c:/progra~1/wolfra~1/mathematica/9.0/mathkernel.exe -mathlink -linkmode Connect `4` -linkname '`2`' -subkernel -noinit >& /dev/null &
```

For test purposes i set 2 remote and 2 local kernels in settings. After that in the notebook i try to call

```
Parallel`Settings`$MathLinkTimeout = 40
LaunchKernels[]
```

and launch Task Manager on both machines. At first two cmd windows appear and instantly close. Then i can see that two MathKernel.exe processes start on BOTH machines, but after nearly 20 seconds kernels shut down on remote machine. Local kernels stay running. After timeout i see an error output.

```
SubKernels`Protected`kernelFlush::time: Operation LinkWrite timed out after 40 seconds.
KernelObject::rdead: Subkernel connected through remote[1.1.1.1] appears dead. >>
SubKernels`Protected`kernelFlush::time: Operation LinkWrite timed out after 40 seconds.
KernelObject::rdead: Subkernel connected through remote[1.1.1.1] appears dead. >>
Out[9]= {KernelObject[7,local],KernelObject[8,local],$Failed,$Failed}
```

What am i missing? A solution would be greatly appreciated.

Update: According to Szabolcs's comments i tried some other things.

1. My ssh command really had an open quote - removed.
2. Changed /dev/null redirections to ssh -f and -n keys.
3. Changed mathkernel.exe to math.exe in the path
4. Tried [this solution](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/94917?_19_redirect=http://community.wolfram.com/content?p_p_id=3&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&_3_groupId=0&_3_keywords=remote&_3_struts_action=%252Fsearch%252Fsearch&_3_redirect=%252Fweb%252Fcommunity%252Fcontent%253Fp_p_id%253D101_INSTANCE_1NAHrkD8jeMH%2526p_p_lifecycle%253D0%2526p_p_state%253Dnormal%2526p_p_mode%253Dview%2526p_p_col_id%253Dcolumn-1%2526p_p_col_pos%253D1%2526p_p_col_count%253D2%2526_101_INSTANCE_1NAHrkD8jeMH_orderVar%253DcreateDate%2526_101_INSTANCE_1NAHrkD8jeMH_tabs1%253D%2526curTag%253Dmathematica%2526tabs2%253DQuestions). It works, so it's not a problem of connection or firewall.

So now my ssh command looks like:

```
ssh -f -n user@remote_ip c:/progra~1/wolfra~1/mathematica/9.0/math -mathlink -linkmode Connect -linkprotocol TCPIP -linkname 'some_port@local_ip,some_port2@local_ip' -subkernel -noinit
```

And it doesn't work with the same behavior.
When i try to run this command in the command line, math.exe starts on remote machine and then closes itself. After that on the local machine in the command line i see this message:

```
LinkConnect::linkc:
-- Message text not found -- (
LinkObject[some_port@local_ip,some_port2@local_ip, 3, 1])
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling the firewalls?  Are you sure the quoting in the launch command, in particular the `-linkname` part, is correct and necessary for Windows?  The `>& /dev/null &` part doesn't sound like it would work on Windows as this is Unix-specific.  The `"` quote is not closed.  I hope some of these comments will help you debug the issue.  Generally, I find debugging remote kernel issues very frustrating, especially on Windows.

Comment: Here's an idea for making sure that the network connection is working correctly between the two computers (and firewalls aren't blocking anything): try starting Mathematica on both machines, and use `LinkCreate` to create a `LinkProtocol -> "TCPIP"` link one one, then use `LinkConnect` to connect to that link from the other computer.  Study the examples on the doc pages of the various `Link*` functions to figure out the correct syntax (unfortunately I don't know it by heart and would need to do the same).

Comment: If it seems you managed to connect this way, see this tutorial on how you can test the connection: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/CallingSubsidiaryMathematicaProcesses.html

Comment: Finally, if you or your institution has 'Premiere Service' then I think you should have access to the [Wolfram Lightweight Grid](https://www.wolfram.com/lightweight-grid-manager/) which will *significantly* simplify using remote subkernels.

Comment: [Cross linking with Community version](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/203567?p_p_auth=ALEz3CwG)

Comment: Thanks for comments. I can't use lightweight grid.